# How to retrieve email address from stdObj PHP

Tags: php

I am new in php and want to retrieve email address from object.
I tried other solutions from SO but not getting.
 Here is my object.

```
{"elements":[{"handle~":{"emailAddress":"test@gmail.com"},"handle":"urn:li:emailAddress:1806662508"}]}
```

Thank You.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/JdHHT

Comment: No worries. Please read the duplicate, it contains a lot of good advice on how to go about this process.